# How to read current location in html5 application

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, html, google-chrome

ASP.NET MVC4 mobile HTML5 online application is running in Android and Apple mobiles and tablets in Chrome, Android and Safari browsers.

Application contains html button

```
<form action='SavePosition'>
  <input type='submit' value='Send' name='position'>
  </form>
```

which should send current location to server. Server should display locations in map.

How to implement this in HTML5/Javascript ? Based on my knowledge html5 does not have such possibility.
I can force users to use Google Chrome browser in all devices if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request the position via javascript.

```
if (navigator.geolocation)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
        console.log("altitude: " + position.coords.altitude);
    })
```

To send the coords via the form you could use some hidden input fields.

You can only request the position in chrome >= 50.0 only via https.

see [W3Schools HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)